# Why are unused parameters only greyed out but not reported?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, linter, pyright

I use VS Code and the unused parameters of functions are only greyed out, but never reported.

How to report those greyed out warning in the problem explorer?

Currently, thanks to the parameter `reportUnusedVariable` in pyright, we can report unused variables, but we cannot report unused parameters.

Comment: There is no relevant function at present https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/3473 https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2875

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Pylance or Pyright, seems like you can't mark unused parameters as errors. They're not always errors - sometimes you need them to conform to some interface.

If you want to prohibit unused parameters anyway, there are other tools such as the [flake8-unused-arguments](https://pypi.org/project/flake8-unused-arguments/) plugin for flake8.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, it's impossible in pyright. And it seems it's a bit more complicated than I thought so I do not think it will be implmented in pyright soon, so  flake8-unused-arguments plugin is the way to go even if this library is still incomplete

Comment: I'm commenting here to say that flake8-unused-arguments has been very useful during the last days. It requires spending some time to choose the right parameters, but overall very good. I now understand why it's not by default in pylance because it's not trivial to setup correctly.